Unable to get response from Next Auth Authorize method with localhost
I've spent like 2 hours with this issue and finally I stumbled upon a random tip that solved my issue.
When testing auth with credentials I was not getting any success pointing to the localhost backend service responsible for auth. The issue was solved by replacing localhost:8080/login with 127.0.0.1:8080/login
I have no idea why but it worked, did not find anything on the docs related to this issue.
I hope this can be worth it for someone who might face the same issue.

I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question
